# How to converge derived classes when the overrode methods are defined the same way but base class is different

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have the following design pattern:

```
class Base:
  # definition omitted

class Derived(Base):
  # definition omitted
```

```
class Mock1(Base):
  def __init__(self, input, args):
    self._input = input
    super(Mock1, self).__init__(args)

  # my_func is defined in Base so we're overriding it
  def my_func(self, for_val):
    # defintion omitted

class Mock2(Derived):
  def __init__(self, input, args):
    self._input = input
    super(Mock2, self).__init__(args)

  # my_func is defined in Base (note it's not defined in Derived) so we're overriding it
  def my_func(self, for_val):
    # defintion omitted
```

My quip is with `Mock1, Mock2` which inherits `Base, Derived`, respectively, which seems to have duplicated code b/c `my_func` is defined the same way in both and the only difference between the 2 classes is what class it's inheriting. Is there a cleaner way to write this?

I believe there is a way to dynamically change which class to inherit but from my understanding it's frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a mixin:

```
class Mixin:
  def my_func(self, for_val):
    # defintion omitted
```

and use it when needed:

```
class Mock2(Mixin, Derived):
    ...
```

**Update:**

Sorry, got the inheritance order wrong: Changed it to: `Mixin, Derived`